# CakePHP Validation no model with two dimensional array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Using CakePHP 1.3, how can I use built-in validation to validate a form that generates a two dimensional array set up as follows and only a model for "Booking". For this example, let's assume I only need to make sure they are required:

```
[Booking] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000141
            [terms] => 1
        )

[Member] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test Name
            [billing_address] => 1234 Park Lane
            [billing_city] => New York
            [billing_zip] => 10001
            [billing_state] => NY
            [billing_country] => US
        )

[Order] => Array
        (
            [theTotal] => 21.64
            [currencyCode] => USD
        )

[CreditCard] => Array
        (
            [card_number] => 1234567890
        )
```

I understand how to use [Multiple Validation Sets](http://snook.ca/archives/cakephp/multiple_validation_sets_cakephp), but since I don't have a model for "Member", "Order", "CreditCard", how can I validate the information?

The reason this form is multidimensional with a model is because I send the data to PayPal for processing and do not save any of the information except for the Booking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Controller

CakePHP passes the `validationErrors` property of each loaded model over to the View class (and then FormHelper class) so validation errors can be displayed. Since the `Controller::render()` method [checks that each model is loaded](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/controller/#l-887), the only way to really make this happen from the controller (without extending the `render()` method) is to create the required models on-the-fly:

```
public function add() {
    // ...
    $this->Member = new Model(null, false); // make fake model with no table
    $this->modelNames[] = 'Member'; // add to list of models
    // perform validation
    if (!Validation::minLength($this->data['Member']['name'], 1)) {
        $this->Member->validationErrors['name'] = 'Please enter you name';
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Edit**

If by "cake-standard" you mean you want to use a `Model::validate` array, this is also possible:

```
public function add() {
    // ...
    $this->Member = new Model(null, false); // make fake model with no table
    $this->modelNames[] = 'Member'; // add to list of models
    // perform validation
    $this->Member->validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', 5),
                'message' => 'Your full name must be at least five characters in length'
            ),
        ),
    );
    $this->Member->set($this->data);
    $this->Member->validates();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. While I was hoping for a more cake-standard way to add two dimensional arrays to a model, I imagine it is not possible. This should do exactly what I was hoping to do.

Comment: See edit for more cake-standard way, though the true cake-standard way is what you are trying to avoid :)

Answer (score 1):

### Model

The validation you are after is a feature of the [Model class](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/model/#l-2466). I would personally create models for each of the above, including your `$validates` array, but setting the `$useTable` property to `false` to prevent it from interacting with your database. This should allow you to use features from the model, such as validation, in places like [your controllers](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1182/Validating-Data-from-the-Controller).

Comment: @deisel Thanks for the comment, but I'm asking if there is a way to do this WITHOUT creating models for each. Basically to save time and complexity at the moment because in the future, we will most likely valiate & save all this information in a different manner using a Booking model for the prices and a User model to hold the billing address and CC number. We already use 45 models in our system and adding another 3 simply for one page of validation before sending to paypal doesn't feel to be the best route to take.

Answer (score 1):

### View

Since CakePHP expects to see real models before passing validation errors to the view, you could also just do it manually to keep things simpler:

```
public function add() {
    // perform validation
    if (!Validation::minLength($this->data['Member']['name'], 1)) {
        $validationErrors['Member']['name'] = 'Please enter you name';
    }
    // etc ...
    $this->set(compact('validationErrors')); // pass to view
}
```

In your view, you can set this to the FormHelper manually:

```
<?php $this->Form->validationErrors = $validationErrors; ?>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Even more simple and a great way to make temporary validation until we implement real models for all the data on the form.

Comment: In Cake 2, it's slightly different: `$validationErrors['Member']['name'][] = 'Please enter you name';`  (appending to an array)